# Proof of invariant angle between $Y$ and $\hat Y$ in $L^2$ regularisation

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators, ridge-regression

On this site is the [following question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486524/angle-between-haty-and-y-stays-the-same-as-lambda-in-ridge-regression) which claims that the $L^2$ regularised OLS preserves the angle between $\hat Y$ and $Y$ irrespective of the value $\lambda$. I have not found any source that makes or proves this assertion, and furthermore the answer in this question eventually resorts to assumptions about standardisations in $X$.I know that $\hat\beta=(X^\mathsf{T}X+\lambda\mathbb{1})^{-1}X^\mathsf{T}Y$, so $\hat Y=X(X^\mathsf{T}X+\lambda\mathbb{1})^{-1}X^\mathsf{T}Y$ and
$$\cos\theta=\frac{Y^\mathsf{T}\hat Y}{||Y||||\hat{Y}||}=\frac{YX(X^\mathsf{T}X+\lambda\mathbb{1})^{-1}X^\mathsf{T}Y}{||Y||||X(X^\mathsf{T}X+\lambda\mathbb{1})^{-1}X^\mathsf{T}Y||}$$
but this doesn't really help. Is the assertion true, and if so how do I get past my sticking point? Thanks!

Comment: The linked post isn't making a *general* statement about ridge regression, it's asking about what special circumstances can give rise to the described behavior. That's why the answer turns on $X$ being orthonormal.